# How to use pandas read_sql with string formating

Tags: python, sql, pandas, postgresql

I'm trying to read a table into a dataframe using the `pandas.io.sql` `read_sql` method. However, I'm getting errors as I need to format my query with a tuple, and some elements of my tuples contain single quotes.

Here is an example of a tuple:

```
tuple = ('dog', 'cat', "wendy's")
```

And my query:

```
query = """SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE my_var IN %s"""
```

I know how to format it to use the `cursor.execute` command, like this:

```
cursor.execute(query,(tup,))
```

But I didn't manage to use the `read_sql` command.

For example

```
psql.read_sql(query,(tup,), connection)
```

throws an error (`'tuple' object has no attribute 'cursor'`).

I also tried using `.format(tup)` but it creates an error near the tuple's element that has a single quote

How can I use `read_sql` with the query I mentioned?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`read_sql` function has a `params`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_sql.html#pandas-read-sql) parameter which you can use to pass the parameters to underlaying `execute` method . ie,

```
psql.read_sql(query, connection, params=(tup,))
                                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: Thank you, can't believe I missed it! I'll accept the answer once I can